# Runtime Exception on Android Firebase Facebook Login

Tags: android, facebook, firebase

I'm getting the following unexplained error, when attempting to make a login button for Facebook in Android:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cs126.chat/cs126.chay.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

My code in Main looks like this:

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private TextView info;
private LoginButton loginButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());          FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
        setContentView(R.layout.login_button);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // Start app
            }
```

I can post the Android manifest XML and the login button XML as well, if any of you believe that those files might be the source of the error.

Here is the android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="cs.melochat">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            tools:replace="android:theme"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Also, here is my login button layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- sourced from https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-
app-cms-23837 !-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, here is my activity main XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- parts of the following code were sourced from this online tutorial:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase-cms-27397 -->

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Input"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/fab"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should post your activity_main.xml

Comment: OK will do in just a sec

Comment: @2____ what does this line means **`setContentView(R.layout.login_button);`**

Comment: Can  you share your layout? I doubt you have a problem in login button as the log reports the NPE for the same.

Comment: I'm using set content view to change the view to the login button, so if you're not logged in the log in button view will pop up

Comment: @SanjogShrestha Yes I can share my layout in just a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this line is the problem

> ```
>     setContentView(R.layout.login_button);
> ```

avoid using setContentView multiple times , you can use fragments instead.
if you don't want to go with fragments you can try the followin approach .

```
 mainActivity = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
 loginButtonLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login_button, null);
```

first set your activity layout like this :

```
setContentView(mainActivity);
```

and then inside your if statement use this :

```
setContentView(loginButtonLayout);
```

your code should be like below:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mainActivity = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
    loginButtonLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.login_button, null);

    setContentView(mainActivity);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(getResources().getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
        setContentView(loginButtonLayout);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // Start app
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need that line to get the login button to pop up, though

Comment: Put your login button view inside activity_main.xml

Comment: I can't because activity main has a lot of other elements in it, it's a different layout entirely

Comment: and kindly post your activity_main so that we can help you

Comment: OK, I can do that then